# python how to convert the use of 'from' to import only

Tags: python, import, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert a simple python program into a standalone executable using installer. Goal is to email an encrypted message. After doing this, the executable failed to run properly and after thinking about it, I think the problems is that pyinstaller is having issues with the imports. A solution on a different post suggested removing the 'from' format.

```
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from multiprocessing import Process
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
```

How would I convert these into import only?
For example, the change for the multiprocessing module:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
p = Process(target=x)
```

to

```
import multiprocessing
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=x)
```

I am not sure is the above is correct, so I have no idea on how to approach the others. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is correct. For another example, you could change all the `email` imports to

```
import email
```

and use the specific parts of the email package like this

```
foo = email.mime.base.MimeBase()
bar = email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart()
...
```

When you only `import email`, the entire `email` name becomes available in your code. To use specific parts of `email` you need to refer to them specifically: `email.foo.bar.X()` as an example.

The `from x import y` differs in that you're importing a specific part of `email` to be available in your code so you can refer to it directly.

Comment: what about in the case of the cryptography module? would it be import cryptography.fernet or import cryptography?

Comment: `import cryptography` to import and to use the specific part of the package that you're using `cryptography.fernet.Fernet`.

Comment: I also don't think the issue is with how you're importing like the other answer said. `from x import y` shouldn't be any different from `import x`, `x.y`.

Comment: you're all probably right, but another thread suggested this solution worked for them and since I am not sure where to begin I thought I'd try this. Still ended up learning something even it doesn't work out :)

Answer (score 2):

The example you provided is correct. You can follow that template for the others as well.

For example:

if you import like this

```
import email.mime.base
```

then you can access this:

```
email.mime.base.MIMEBase
```

I only have a little experience with pyinstaller but from what I understand, it shouldn't have a problem with `from x import y` syntax.